# NodeJS+web3 - contract method call not a function

Tags: web3js, nodejs, ethereumjs

I trying to use nodejs with web3.js to do the full process of compile,delpoly and method call.After read the [api](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#contract-methods) here. I found the contract-methods.

```
myContractReturned.call().getCount();
```

But when I use it like this, I always got following error:

```
myContractReturned.call().getCount();
                   ^


TypeError: myContractReturned.call is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/admin/develop/blockchain_workspace/truffle3/main/web3InAction.js:70:20)
    at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:605:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:420:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:139:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:535:3
```

After search the internet,I found [here](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/blob/master/example/contract.html) that web3.js with javascript seems good.Did anybody have used nodejs with web3.js,any help will appreciate.Environment are as following:

```
$ node -v
v7.2.0
$ testrpc
EthereumJS TestRPC v3.0.3
```

Solidity source here:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

contract Calc{
  //simple storage
  uint count;

  //change state
  function add(uint a, uint b) returns(uint){
    count++;
    return a + b;
  }

  //no state change
  function getCount() constant returns (uint){
    return count;
  }
}
```

Full code as following:

```
let Web3 = require('web3');
let web3;

if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
    web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
} else {
    // set the provider you want from Web3.providers
    web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));
}

let from = web3.eth.accounts[0];

let source = "pragma solidity ^0.4.0;contract Calc{ uint count;  function add(uint a, uint b) returns(uint){    count++;    return a + b;  }  function getCount() returns (uint){    return count;  }}";

let calcCompiled = web3.eth.compile.solidity(source);

console.log(calcCompiled);
console.log("ABI definition:");
console.log(calcCompiled["info"]["abiDefinition"]);

let abiDefinition = calcCompiled["info"]["abiDefinition"];
let calcContract = web3.eth.contract(abiDefinition);

let deployCode = calcCompiled["code"];

let deployeAddr = web3.eth.accounts[0];

let myContractReturned = calcContract.new({
    data: deployCode,
    from: deployeAddr
}, function(err, myContract) {
    if (!err) {

        if (!myContract.address) {
            console.log("contract deploy transaction hash: " + myContract.transactionHash) 

        } else {
            console.log("contract deploy address: " + myContract.address) 
        }
    }
});


console.log("returned deployed didn't have address now: " + myContractReturned.address);

//nodeJS?
myContractReturned.call().getCount();
```

Comment: please add your solidity in a formatted separate file and show accordingly, otherwise it's hard to read.

Comment: Thank you for your comment,sorry for that. I have add the solidity source file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few things:

1. Your function `getCount` should be `constant` (`function getCount() constant returns (uint)` should be constant. Otherwise

   a) you pay for gas and

   b) since you anyway don't change any state, this doesn't even make sense

   c) in web3.js you get a transaction hash back when calling a non-constant 
   function and not a return value, I don't think you want that.
2. You don't need `call`. You invoke a smart contract function call via `myContractReturned.getCount(function(error, result) { console.log('result: ' + result + , error: ' + error); } );` [as described](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#contract-methods)
3. You need to place this inside the callback handler `function(err, myContract) {` and check if you got an address. **spoiler alert:**  the callback handler is being called twice: first time when you got a txHash, second time when your contract get mined! [Check the example in the doc](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethcontract) and basically check that you got an address. Only then proceed to interacting with the contract.

Comment: Hi, @Sebastian, just now I add the `constant` to the `getCount()`, but still got the error of `myContractReturned.getCount is not a function`. Before that, I have print the return object, there is a `call()` method here.But I don't known how can I use it. any way, thank you for your answer.

Comment: I edited my answer, you have issues with the double callback upon contract deployment. Just in case you're wondering: Yes, I also think thats a design flaw and this will hopefully be fixed in web3.js release 1.0

Comment: Yep,@Sebastian,you are right,I should use the contract method in the function callback.I was misleaded by the [api](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#contract-methods) which focused on the address to be set.I didn't even known the contract method is to be set as well, or maybe any other error.